# Complex MySQL Group By

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains results from football matches between two teams. Firstly I want to have a drop down menu of the teams. This should be simply something like SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY Team_A

But a team could be missed if they only ever appear in the Team_B column. Is it possible to group columns Team_A and Team_B so that I could output all unique teams across both columns?

Comment: Can you fix this sentence part ? `if they only ever appear `

Comment: Put schema and sample data in post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all the names, then use `union`.  This also removes duplicates:

```
select TeamA from table union
select TeamB from table
```

Comment: @Max : But you wanted TWO columns!

Comment: @nl-x . . . The *data* is in two columns.  The goal is stated as:  "I want to have a drop down menu of the teams."  That sounds like one column for the results.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the right data, but . . .

```
select team_a as team_name
from test
union
select team_b
from test
order by team_name;
```

You should probably have foreign key references to a table of teams. If you had *that*, with the obligatory unique constraint on the team's name, you'd just need to

```
select team_name
from teams
order by team_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just mean:

```
group by Team_A, Team_B
```

?

This will group by the combination of Team_A and Team_B

**edit:** To end up with TWO columns, each having a unique list of teams that already existed in that column (exactly as described by OP):

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM
(SELECT Team_A, @ida := ifnull(@ida,0) + 1 AS ida FROM table GROUP BY Team_A) AS a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Team_B, @idb := ifnull(@idb,0) + 1 AS idb FROM table GROUP BY Team_B) AS b
ON a.ida=b.idb
and isnull(@ida := null) and isnull(@idb := null) -- reset @ida and @idb

UNION ALL -- turn the left and right join into full outer join

SELECT c.*, d.* FROM
(SELECT Team_A, @idc := ifnull(@idc,0) + 1 AS idc FROM table GROUP BY Team_A) AS c
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT Team_B, @idd := ifnull(@idd,0) + 1 AS idd FROM table GROUP BY Team_B) AS d
ON c.idc=d.idd
and isnull(@idc := null) and isnull(@idd := null) -- reset @idc and @idd
WHERE c.idc is null -- prevent doubles in the full outer join
```

Comment: this does n't give the required
it gives the results where combination of (team A and team B) are same

Comment: If he doesn't want the combination, but wants each team_A in one column, and each team_b in the other column... Then what to do if there are more Team_A than Team_B ?

Comment: basically he wants a list of all the team names in team a and team b
not the combination

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION` like this:

```
SELECT Team_A AS TeamName FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT Team_B AS TeamName FROM table
```

to get the distinct listing of teams. But I have to say, you **really** need to restructure your database. You should have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Teams (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

and then a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Scores (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    HomeTeamId INT NOT NULL,
    AwayTeamId INT NOT NULL,
    HomeTeamScore INT NOT NULL,
    AwayTeamScore INT NOT NULL
)
```

and that would allow not only a more straight forward selection of teams:

```
SELECT Name FROM Teams
```

but it would also build some real database integrity because you could build foreign keys and you wouldn't be using simple string values to indicate key values.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with using strings as keys in any modern dbms.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall': I will agree with that -as long as the database is still properly normalized. However, one thing to note would be that string keys can't leverage statistical indexes and thus slow over time because of that.

Comment: What's a statistical index? (That's not a term in English--maybe a difference in language?) Link to docs?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall': SQL Server has a concept called a [Statistical Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188038.aspx), and in short it allows the query execution engine to **know** 2 comes after 1 rather than scanning for it, *though I admittedly don't fully understand the implementation**, I know it works on integers as the table grows. Here is a [blog on it too](http://blog.idera.com/sql-server/understanding-sql-server-statistics/).

Comment: CREATE STATISTICS has to do with giving SQL Server's optimizer better cardinality estimates. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the column's data type. Also, I'm pretty sure SQL Server knows 2 comes after 1 without additional statistics. I'm still not sure *statistical index* is an applicable term here.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall': you may be right, I may need to revisit my understanding of the statistical index. Thanks!